# Mesira on a pauper

Tags: tzedakah-charity, gezel-stealing, mesirah, police-authorities

Let's say I was in a kosher store and I noticed a Jewish homeless man who is halachically an "ani" and i notice him pickpocketing some food.

Would i be allowed to tell the store owner or police or would it be mesira?

Comment: Similar to egla arufah where the elders of the city take responsibility since if they would have fed him he wouldn't have ended up dead, is it the community's fault that he ended up stealing?

Comment: You are probably obligated to inform the store owner since he is losing money (לא תעמוד...) ,but there is a right way to go about it ,seicheil has to be used

Comment: This is an interesting question to analyze as a hypothetical, however as framed this is a solicitation for personalized advice - which goes against MiYodeya guidelines (there's a prominent reminder in the sidebar). This post will likely be voted closed. You can find guidance on crafting a better question here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/asking and what topics are considered to be on-topic here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Not telling _feels_ a bit like a problem with לא תשא פני דל ([Vayikra 19:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.19.15?lang=bi&lang2=en),  [MT Sanhedrin 20:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1172743/jewish/Sanhedrin-vehaOnashin-haMesurin-lahem-Chapter-20.htm#v4)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dayan Weiss in Minchas Yitzchok [8:148](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14683&st=&pgnum=610) discusses at length the issue of mesira when there’s a public danger/menace or potential danger. Even in such cases, he says that the perpetrator must be warned beforehand and preferably by Bais Din.

In your case, you would be obligated to tell the store owner (assuming that a kosher store is owned by a Jew) as per the Chofetz Chaim in [Klal 10](https://www.sefaria.org/Chafetz_Chaim%2C_Part_One%2C_The_Prohibition_Against_Lashon_Hara%2C_Principle_10.1.1?lang=bi&with=Be%27er%20Mayim%20Chaim) and Be’er Mayim Chaim there.

However, to go to the police, would be problematic. Unless you warned him, told the owner, went to bais din, and he’s still at it. In that case perhaps he’s a public menace and it would be permitted based on the above Teshuva.

P.S. I am not sure why his financial status makes a difference. Stealing is prohibited for all Jews in all instances, No matter the desperation.